# Cannot find symbol Menu and MenuItem

Tags: java, android, android-menu

I am trying to build Android app everything worked fine but suddenly my Home Activity is throwing me an error not able to find symbol Menu and MenuItem. I am not sure what it went wrong. I rebuild the project and invalidate and cache the project but still its throwing me an error. Any help is highly appreciated.

```
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
```

**Sample Code**

```
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;

public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.home, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

Comment: share your code.

Comment: Might be action_settings menu item not available.Share error logs

Comment: Added sample code with the post

Comment: can you share full code. the current code look ok

Comment: The problem is I am not able to import Menu. If I import Menu then this code works.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this.

Build-> Clean Project

Build-> Rebuild Project